# C# class library changes not being shown when referenced in another project

Tags: c#, dll, class-library

I have a class library that has a few methods and everything works fine when i reference it in another project.

Now i wanted to add an overload to one of the methods, when i made the change and re-referenced it in my other project, it does not show the overloaded method and gives the standard " method has 1 param but is invoked with 2".

I have also tried to add an optional parameter to the method instead of the overload and the same problem occurs.

If i however were to just change the logic in the method, These changes will be there when i re-reference the library.

Does anyone have any insight on why this may be happening??

Sample code

```
public class OptumHealth
{
    public CreateJobModelResponse CreateOptumHealthJob(OptumHealthHelper helper)
    {
        return CreateOptumHealthJob(helper, false);
    }

    public CreateJobModelResponse CreateOptumHealthJob(OptumHealthHelper helper, bool isUpdate)
    {
        var response = new CreateJobModelResponse();

        //stuff

        return response;
    }
}
```

I can call the first method, and that calls the second method correctly. I cannot call the second method directly though.

Comment: have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project..? also do you have the using section of that dll added to the other project.. can you show what your namespace for both .cs files look like...?

Comment: are you sure you have the project references set up correctly? sounds like you're referencing the `.dll` file instead of making a project reference

Comment: Are you referencing the library by the DLL or by the project? If you have projects in the same solution you should almost always use project references instead of DLL ones.

Comment: Sounds like you changed the method, as opposed to adding an overload? Perhaps you could add a simplified version of your code change to illustrate what you're doing?

Comment: @SeanWagner I could have told you that without having tried it.. I think that you should show your code perhaps you're referencing a method incorrectly or your method signature is not truly an overloaded method.. hard to determine without seeing the method that you added

Comment: The class library and the other project are in separate solutions. I am referencing the .dll file. give me a few minutes and ill give you simple mock up of what i am doing.

Comment: Make sure you're referencing the same .dll that you're making changes to (i.e. retail/debug)...

Comment: @SeanWagner just add the method and the other one in which you thought you were creating an overloaded method.. if you are not sure on how to create overloaded methods.. do a google search